# Strange hidden NaN values in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a strange problem with values in pandas dataframes sometimes appearing as NaN and sometimes not. I have not managed to create a reproducible example but I will try to describe as best I can.

So, I have a detaframe with a multi index and a bunch of columns which I access with .loc:

```
>>> df1.loc[("2019","Ley"), :]
crop_group           Ley
area              64.096
organic        17.605815
unharvested          NaN
grazed               NaN
green                NaN
excl_grain        64.096
```

All fine so far. And I can access a specific column such as "area":

```
>>> df1.loc[("2019","Ley"), "area"]
64.096
```

But then I try to access "excl_grain":

```
>>> df1.loc[("2019","Ley"), "excl_grain"]
nan
```

And I get "nan" even though when I accessed all columns "excl_grain" had a value. Also, the value shows if I instead access it like this:

```
>>> df1.loc[("2019","Ley"), :]["excl_grain"]
64.096
```

Any pointers on what could be the problem here is highly appreciated.

Cheers!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you print `df1.loc[("2019","Ley"), "excl_grain"]` and `df1.loc[("2019","Ley"), :]["excl_grain"]` without any modification in df1 i.e. one after the other and see if the issue still persists?

Comment: Thanks! Those prints were made without modifying df1 in between. But, I managed to fix the problem, but I still find it a bit strange. What happened was that I had calculated "excl_grain" by multiplying "area" in df1 with a column in another dataframe (let's call it df2) containing some nans resulting (of course) in nans in "excl_grain". When I realised this, I fixed the nans in df2 and redid the calculation of "excl_grain". After this I encountered the strange problem. Finally I deleted df1 and redid the calculations, this time without first imputing nans in "excl_grain" which fixed it.